# Deceptive affix changes?

Tags: etymology, affixes

I exemplify with the following, but I ask this in general. How can I learn more about affixes that change meaning, especially those that are 'upended into' their antonyms?

For example, I was researching the etymology of surreptitious:

> [surreptitious (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=surreptitious+&searchmode=none)
>   mid-15c., from Latin *surrepticius* "stolen, furtive, clandestine," from *surreptus*, past participle of *surripere* "seize secretly, take away, steal, plagiarize," from assimilated form of *sub* "from under" (hence, "secretly;" see [sub-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sub-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *rapere* "to snatch" (see [rapid](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rapid&allowed_in_frame=0)).

How did the *sub-* prefix invert to its antonym *sur-* (French for 'on')?

Yet (to my surprise), 'subreption {noun}' maintained the *sub-* prefix.

Comment: Mostly changes from original forms in borrowings have to do with when and where the word entered the target language, what it sounded like then in the source language, and what the phonology and phonosemantics of the target language was like at that time and place. It's the variable influence of these effects on the original forms that results in variation. And like anything living and emergent, it's only detectable ex post facto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't an example of antonymy, but of accidental similarity. The Latin prefix *sub-* could be assimilated into *sur-* before an *r*. This is not the same as French *sur* 'over', which is from Latin *super*.